# Ajax Base Googlebot Crawl

Tags: gwt, seo, googlebot, google-crawlers

This is the website which we released last week(One page website) http://www.itslayer.com/

We are getting problem to test this with Google Webmaster tool. We developed the website as per the doc - https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Please let us know how can we test Ajax base website with googlebot and whether our implementation is correct.

Thanks in advance for suggestion. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this : http://www.itslayer.com/?_escaped_fragment_=md5 and see that you don't have content in it.

The "HTML snapshots" must be what real user see after loading the page with JS.
In consequence, the  URL with `?_escaped_fragment_` must return the whole HTML page. Not only `<title>` & `<meta>`.

Read further on [Google doc : How do I create an HTML snapshot?](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot)